# How does TYPO3 generate the index of a file, as seen in its XML-website export data?

Tags: file, indexing, export, typo3

The following XML-code is an excerpt of a file generated using the TYPO3 website export feature. The export feature was configured to include the files used on the website:

```
...
<files_fal type="array">
    <file index="008f35a8201e50eb24a9667092782ec0" type="array">
        <filename>somefilename.jpg</filename>
        <filemtime>1603259011</filemtime>
        <content base64="1">...</conten>
        <content_sha1>...</content_sha1>
    </file>
</files_fal>
...
```

What I'd like to know is, how exactly the value of the index attribute (008f35a8201e50eb24a9667092782ec0) is generated in such a case. Thank you for any clues in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself now (by looking into the PHP source code of TYPO3)

The string is created during export by concatenation of the **storage uid** of the file in the sys_file table, the **identifer_hash** from the same table with a **:** inbetween.

The resulting string is then turned into a hash using **md5**.

In pseudo-code:

```
hash = make_md5( storage_uid + ':' + identifier_hash )
```

Depending on how your md5 making function works, it may be necessary to encode the string as binary beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty much like one of the hashes stored in the sys_file table. Should be identifier_hash to make any sense.

Comment: I am aware of several hashes in the export data/the sys_file table and could replicate all of them successfully, except this one, which does not stem from the sys_file table or any other TYPO3 table it seems. The code is somewhat shorter than the other hashes (sha1) and neither the name nor the the context provide any hint, what type of encoding/encryption was used, which data was put into it or in what format.the data was in originally. The code may stem from an entry in the file system or was specifically generated for the export.